# How to use android default browser during automation testing

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, browser-automation

I want to automate some test cases in android default browser (not chrome). Here is my desire capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().android();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "browser");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.ANDROID);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "My Device");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.browser");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
```

When I run the any testcases through appium, output is:

```
A new session could not be created. (Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: com.android.browser is not installed on device a5cde43e
```

If anybody have any idea how to solve this problem, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure appPackage is correct that you are passing

Comment: `Original error: unknown error: com.android.browser is not installed on device a5cde43e` - the error says that the android browser is not installed.

Comment: I am not sure, though. How do I know my default android browser's appPackage name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either of the one activity below,

```
//Android Default Browser
//          capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.sec.android.app.sbrowser");
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.browser");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.browser/.BrowserMainActivity");
```

Comment: Sorry, bro. Same problem :(

Comment: TRY installing an app called activity launcher, which list all ur apps, select the browser inside it , whihc show the package, activity name of the app

Comment: I have installed activity launcher and found the package and activity name. Finally, I have run my test in default browser. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used below code and I am able to open default browser on my Meizu device

```
        new DesiredCapabilities();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"81HEBM6245N7");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "5.0.1"); 

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(url, capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.quit();
    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        System.out.println("URL init error");
    }
```

Comment: I have used above code. I have found: A new session could not be created. (Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: com.android.browser is not installed on device a5cde43e

Comment: Okay, @Autobot . You have used appPackage,appActivity capabilities as well. remove those and try

Comment: When I tried your code, I did that. But I found that error. Anyway, I have used my current default appPackage and appActivity and its running. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Okay.. I will give it a try one more time on other device/os . I am curious to explore more on this. I will let you know if I get any finding